# adding variable in jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, element

Im attempting to select an element via its title, which is stored in a variable:

```
$('.images').hover(function(){
    var img = $(this).attr("title");
    $(".image-border[title='img']").addClass('show');
}
```

however as you can imagine, the variable is being treated as part of the string... is this even a possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably going to get answers telling you to use string concatenation, such as:

<sub>**Don't do it this way**</sub>

```
$('.images').hover(function () {
  var img = $(this).attr('title');
  $('.image-border[title="' + img + '"]').addClass('show');
});
```

This is a bad idea. You haven't escaped the value stored in `img`, and it could break the selector.

The *right* way to do this sort of check is to select everything you can statically, and then [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) the results to only include the ones that match the dynamic value:

<sub>**Do it this way**</sub>

```
$('.images').hover(function () {
  var img = $(this).attr('title');
  $('.image-border[title]').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('title') === img;
  }).addClass('show');
});
```

Comment: this was more of the approach i was looking for. security is important for even the most minute things! - thanks

Comment: Okay, now this looks better.

Comment: Use this selector to run through the filter function, `.image-border[title]`. Not that it changes the answer finely put by @zzzzBov. It simply reduces the number of elements to be tested as it only provides the .image-border elements which have a title attribute in them present.